# Sending Longitude, Latitude & Phone Number to mysql database - Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, latitude-longitude

I have made an app which already recieves the longitude latitude and phone number.

I need to store these in a mysql database and I have no experience with mysql and php.

Can anyone please help me, maybe with some tutorials.

Comment: This is a link to a [decent article](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Insert-and-Update-Statement-Use-Prepared-Statement-P552.html) showing how to insert data using PDO and a prepared statement. It is part of a series that explains the PDO object rather nicely.

Comment: This doesn't describe anything about the Android part

Comment: You said you had no experience with mysql and PHP, that was a link to a good PHP and Mysql tutorial.

Comment: Do you need to store it in a mysql server og just in a database, maybe on the phone? (sqlite)

Comment: Mysql server. I need to acces the info with a different OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create MySql Database on a server and call Web service to add that data on the server using Php.

Look at this tutorial . Here you can find how to send and receive data using php web service.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php

Comment: Isn't there an easy way to create an php file and a simple way to put the lon lat en phone number in mysql database